# DevExpress DockLayoutManager dock panel width

Tags: wpf, devexpress

I am working with a wpf aplication and I am using a DockLayoutManager. In this DockLayoutManager I am added a LayoutPanel which is docked right. While start up the application, panel is in auto hide sate. While opening the panel, the width is less. I want to increase the LayoutPanel width default. How can i change the LayoutPanel width in xaml.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the goal, you can set the [AutoHideGroup.AutoHideSize](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfDockingAutoHideGroup_AutoHideSizetopic) attached property in your LayoutPanel :

```
<dxdo:LayoutPanel Caption="Panel1" dxdo:AutoHideGroup.AutoHideSize="150,100">
    ...
</dxdo:LayoutPanel>
```